# Configure OAuth2 access for shop users

Tags: symfony, sylius, hwioauthbundle

I would like to add social connect buttons in my Sylius shop but I can't manage to do that.
I installed HWIOAuthBundle via composer :

```
$ composer require hwi/oauth-bundle
```

Then, according to [HWIOAuthBundle documentation](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md), here are my config files:

**app/config/routing.yml**

```
hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix:   /login

facebook_login:
    path: /login/check-facebook
```

**app/config/config.yml**

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_names: [secured_area]
    resource_owners:
        any_name:
            type:                facebook
            client_id:           <client_id>
            client_secret:       <client_secret>
            options:
                display: popup #dialog is optimized for popup window
                auth_type: rerequest # Re-asking for Declined Permissions
```

**app/config/security.yml**

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        anonymous: ~
        oauth:
          resource_owners:
              facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
          login_path:        /login
          use_forward:       false
          failure_path:      /login

          oauth_user_provider:
              service: sylius.oauth.user_provider
```

When I start the server, I get this error :

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]                                              
The service "sylius.oauth.user_provider" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sylius.factory.admin_user_oauth".
```

Do you have any idea on how to fix it ? The documentation of Sylius is pretty brief and even by searching in commit comments, I can't any clue.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Does someone  has a simple guide on how to integrate HWIOAuthBundle into Sylius ?

Answer (score 0):

So I will answer to myself.
It seems to be a bug and there is allready a pull request in order to fix it :
https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/pull/5763